# Выполнение SqlBulkCopy и Entity Framework в одной транзакции

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Открываю транзакцию в EF вызовом:

```
db.Database.BeginTransaction()
```

делаю некоторые вещи и далее, хочу выполнить операции с большим кол-вом вставок через BulkCopy, но таким образом, что бы если в EF или в BC будут ошибки, что бы все откатилось.

Можно ли это сделать?

Пытался скормить BC `db.Database.CurrentTransaction`, но не принимает...

Answer (score 1):

Составил по примеру из [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/transaction-and-bulk-copy-operations#using-existing-transactions).

```cs
    //Set up the bulk copy object inside the transaction. 
    using (DbContextTransaction transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader())
        {
            try 
            {
                // Здесь можно выполнить операции с помощью EF...
                // <...>
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(
                           destinationConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity,
                           transaction.UnderlyingTransaction as SqlTransaction))
                {
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10;
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =
                        "dbo.BulkCopyDemoMatchingColumns";
                    // Write from the source to the destination.
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                }
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ключевой момент:

```
transaction.UnderlyingTransaction as SqlTransaction
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, для чего вы получаете CurrentTransaction - чтобы проверить, создалась ли транзакция?

Вам нужно объявить транзакцию, получить ее при открытии транзакции:

```
public DbContextTransaction DbTransaction { set; get; }

DbTransaction=db.Database.BeginTransaction();
```

В случае отсутствия ошибок - закоммитить ее:

```
DbTransaction.Commit();
```

При наличии ошибок - откатить:

```
DbTransaction.Rollback();
```

Comment: А разве этот объект сможет принять SqlBulkCopy? Насколько я знаю, он только SqlTransaction принимает

Comment: Насколько я понял, SqlBulkCopy при выполнении может принимать transaction как один из атрибутов, судя по похожим вопросам, ему надо передавать не саму открытую транзакцию, а ее UnderlyingTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

ТУт уже знания SQL Server нужны. Если не ошибаюсь, Bulk должен быть атомарной операцией и накладывается как одна транзакция (можно только настраивать конфигурацию транзакции их до 6 штук в MS SQL), что привет к ее  откату, если она приводит к ошибке. 
Следовательно коммитить нечего.